# Duplication of row cell borders in UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, scroll, uitableview, border

I have a search controller in UITableViewController. Everything is OK when I'm scrolling through the records, but the problem appears when I'm in search mode. The result set returned from search controller behaves very strange. If I start to scroll then the whole rows with cells and borders start to scroll normally but then the initial cell borders appears on top of the screen and stays fixed at the initial border positions. So I'm experiencing double row cell borders that overlaps. Does anybody know what causes such behavior?

UPDATE: it looks like if the search result contains more rows (like 9) then the scroll behaves normally. But if there are 3 or 4 rows then those weird fixed cell borders appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem. The thing is I realized that there are different tableViews when using search: the tableView and searchResultsTableView. The latter is accessible via self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView. So, I have a delegate method that reacts to input search text:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

    if ([searchText length] == 0) {

      [self resetSearchFilters];

    } else {    

       //apply search criteria
   }

  //[self.tableView reloadData]; // that was causing duplication

  [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
}
```

It looks like I needed to reload searchResultsTableView instead of main tableView.